# REGEXMATCH to match cell value in more than one other cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I used this formula

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(K11, "BN11|BT11|BZ11|CF11|CL11"),"YES", "NO")
```

to find if a word in `BN11` OR `BT11` OR `BZ11` OR `CF11` OR `CL11` is mentioned in cell `K11`, but it's not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you felt you got a working solution here. But it's also not clear to me whether you are trying to test whether any target cell in the righthand columns can be found within the Col-B text, or if you are trying to test whether the entire Col-B text is found in one or more of the righthand target cells. In either case, I believe you can benefit from one or more of the new functions Google Sheets just rolled out; but I'd need to be clear on your goal before making a specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH({C2&F2&I2&L2&O2},LOWER(B2)),"YES","NO")
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

Try this formula

```
=INDEX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H11,I11:K11)),TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Nope. This is the formula to check if a word from BN11 is in K11.  =if(REGEXMATCH(K11, BN11),"YES", "NO"). I just need to check more than 1 cell, not only BN11, but also cells BT11, BZ11, ect.

Comment: It searches all 3 cells. I11,J11,K11. Not just one cell. As for YES, NO try: `=INDEX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H11,I11:K11)),"YES","NO"))`

Comment: It says: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in I15

Comment: That is because you have data in I15. If still having issues please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAd0rhbRqXv5Xud-R0BBFunXizSQc-Xc4E4akO1mcTM/edit?usp=sharing - what I need is search all columns named word for a word that is mentioned in column Title. If ANY of the "word" columns has if return YES as Value.

Comment: Check your sheet. Try this: `=REGEXMATCH({C2&F2&I2&L2&O2},LOWER(B2))`

Comment: Thanks, man. Left a comment for you :)

Comment: =IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B2),{C2,F2,I2,L2,O2}), "YES", "NO") - this is the one that did the job for me. Thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(K11), "bn11|bt11|bz11|cf11|cl11"),"YES", "NO")
```

[image]

Comment: Nope. Not sure you understood. I'm searching for word in cells BN11, BT11, ect. So I need to find if a word from those cells is mentioned in K11 cell. The part with Lower cases I managed to figure out :) Thanks

Comment: @ChristianVelev Okay.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` with pipe `|` (Regex OR):

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(K11, "(?i)"&JOIN("|",BN11,BT11,BZ11,CF11,CL11)),"YES", "NO")
```